# jQuery & PHP : How can I reorder a list items by their class?

Tags: php, jquery, list, smarty, reorderlist

Firstly, sorry for my bad english, I hope I'll explain well my problem...

So, I'm trying to learn developping and actually I have this code :

```
<ul>
    <li class="odd ajax_block_product {if $smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedProducts.first}first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedProducts.last}last_item{else}item{/if} {if $smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedProducts.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 0}last_item_of_line{elseif $smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedProducts.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 1} {/if} {if $smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedProducts.iteration > ($smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedProducts.total - $totModulo)}last_line{/if}">...</li>    
    <li class="even ajax_block_category {if $smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedCategories.first}first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.myhomeFeaturedCategories.last}last_item{else}item{/if}">...</li>
</ul>
```

The UL populates automaticly with smarty, so at the end my HTML is like this :

```
<ul>
    <li class="odd">1</li>     
    <li class="odd">2</li>
    <li class="odd">3</li>     
    <li class="odd">4</li>

    <li class="even">5</li>     
    <li class="even">6</li>
    <li class="even">7</li>     
    <li class="even">8</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that I want to alternate EVEN and ODD classes with jQuery or PHP, but I didn't find how. 
I would like to make this :

```
     <ul>
        <li class="odd">1</li>     
        <li class="even">5</li>
        <li class="odd">2</li>     
        <li class="even">6</li>

        <li class="odd">3</li>     
        <li class="even">7</li>
        <li class="odd">4</li>     
        <li class="even">8</li>
    </ul>
```

Can somebody tell me how I need to do this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to handle this within your smarty loop?

Comment: 1) You should update your server-side code , there should be only 1 loop generating odd and even items, alternating the class. 2) You may also want to check CSS pseudo-classes `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` that are a much cleaner way to do what you're probably trying to do, but not supported by older browsers

Comment: Hello, the solutions proposed here is for adding classes to ODD or EVEN elements. But I need to reorder them. I want to say that my first loop will be always displayed in ODD columns and my second alwayw in EVEN columns. I think is possible to make it in php also but I don't know how... May be the code of my loop will help you?
I will edit my post. Thank's for helping me!

Comment: If you want two columns, wouldn't it be easier (and a lot more logical) to make two different uls and put them next to each other with css? then you would end up with two lists, one for products and another for categories. It just doesn't seem correct to randomly scramble data just for presentation reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how to do this. Thank you all for helping me ! Here's the code for someone in my situation :

```
$(function () {
    var $oddArray = new Array();
    var $evenArray = new Array();
    $('ul#shuffle li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('product')) {
            $oddArray.push($(this).html());
        } else {
            $evenArray.push($(this).html());
        }
    });
    var newLi = new Array();
    var index;
    var oddIndex = 0;
    var evenIndex = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < ($oddArray.length + $evenArray.length); index++) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            console.log("ODD");
            if ($oddArray[oddIndex] != undefined)
                newLi += '<li>' + $oddArray[oddIndex] + '</li>';
            oddIndex++;
        } else {
            console.log("EVEN");
            if ($evenArray[evenIndex] != undefined)
                newLi += '<li>' + $evenArray[evenIndex] + '</li>';
            evenIndex++;
        }
    }
    delete $oddArray;
    delete $evenArray;
    $('ul#shuffle').html(newLi);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be a bit complicated :

```
$(function () {
    var $items = $('li');
    var odd = $items.filter('.odd').get();
    var even = $items.filter(':not(.odd)').get();
    var mixed = [];
    while (odd.length) {
        mixed.push(odd.shift());
        if (even.length) {
            mixed.push(even.shift());
        }
    }
    if (even.length) {
        mixed = mixed.concat(even);
    }
    $('ul').append(mixed);
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/unzxv/.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo class like below,

```
li:nth-child(even) { color: green; }
li:nth-child(odd) { color: blue; }
```

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/UCBGJ/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use smarty's [cycle](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.cycle.tpl):

```
 <li class="{cycle values="odd,even"} ajax_block_product....
```

Comment: Yes I tryed it too, but my 2 `<LI>` have a different loop dor displaying content. The first `<LI>` is displaying products, the second one displays categories, then my `<UL>` populates automaticly from the data base. And in first position I have all my products, and when is the end of products I have all my categories. So I would to mix them for displaying : one product, one category, one product, one category... But I'm a beginner and I don't know how I can switch between 2 `<LI>` to make them appear in this order.